# Minimum of ratio of sine functions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

In the below question, $k$ will always denote an odd integer greater than or equal to $3$.

**My question**: Is there an explicit sequence $\{a_k\}$ with $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_k=-\infty$ such that for every $k$,
$$\min_{-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq  \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(k(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})}\geq a_k?$$
By explicit, I mean that $a_k$ should have a closed-form expression. If possible, I would also prefer to have $a_k=p(k)$ for some polynomial $p$.

**Remarks**:

1. If we replace the minimum by the maximum, then it can be shown that for every integer $k\geq 1$,
   $$\max_{-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq  \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(k(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})}=k.$$
2. I consider only odd integers $k\geq 3$ because for even integers $2k\geq 2$, it can be shown that
   $$\min_{-\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq  \frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin(2k(x+\frac{\pi}{2}))}{\sin(x+\frac{\pi}{2})}=-2k.$$
3. Due to periodicity, all maximum and minimum can be taken over $\mathbb{R}$ instead of just over $|x|\leq \pi/2$.
4. The motivation for this question comes from trying to estimate an error term in a infinite sine series representing the solution to the heat equation, but I won't go into the details.

Comment: Suggestion: show that the minimum in question is at least $-1/\sin(\frac\pi k)$, and then use a polynomial (indeed linear) lower bound for $\sin y$ for small positive $y$.

Comment: @GregMartin thanks. Roughly speaking, what is the heuristic/strategy for the lower bound? Then I should be able to figure out the technical details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the equivalent and more convenient
$$
\min_{0\le y\le\pi/2} \frac{\sin ky}{\sin y}.
$$
The function takes negative values, but it is positive for $0\le y\le \frac\pi k$; therefore
$$
\min_{0\le y\le\pi/2} \frac{\sin ky}{\sin y} = \min_{\pi/k\le y\le\pi/2} \frac{\sin ky}{\sin y} \ge \min_{\pi/k\le y\le\pi/2} \frac{-1}{\sin y} = \frac{-1}{\sin(\pi/k)}.
$$
Since $\sin 0=0$ and $\sin\frac\pi3 = \frac{\sqrt3}2$ and $\sin y$ is convex on $[0,\frac\pi3]$, we have $\sin y \ge \frac{\sqrt3/2}{\pi/3}y = \frac{3\sqrt3}{2\pi}y$ on $[0,\frac\pi3]$. Thus
$$
\min_{0\le y\le\pi/2} \frac{\sin ky}{\sin y} \ge \frac{-1}{\sin(\pi/k)} \ge \frac{-1}{\frac{3\sqrt3}{2\pi} \frac\pi k} = \frac{-2}{3\sqrt3}k. \tag{$*$}
$$
Moreover, since
$$
\frac{\sin ky}{\sin y}\bigg|_{y=3\pi/2k} = \frac{-1}{\sin3\pi/2k} \le \frac{-1}{3\pi/2k} = \frac{-2}{3\pi} k,
$$
the lower bound ($*$) is best possible up to a factor of $\frac\pi{\sqrt3} \approx 1.8138$.